# What means dotted constraint in Xcode 7?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

[image]

What does this dotted constraint mean?

How I've understood it, is that it means it is a weak constraint?

Is that correct? And if so, how can I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 9):

Selected the constraint then set it less than 1000

[image]

Then

[image]

It means the priority is lower than default,so if there another constraint conflict with this one,this one is breaked

Answer (score 5):

The dotted constraints mean that the priority is set to lower than 1000.

I attached two images, one with 1000 (required) and one for High, which is lower than 1000, or to be precise, between 750 and 1000.

[image: priority required = 1000]

[image: priority high = between 750 and 1000]

see also this layout guide below, copied from  [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH10-SW1)

> **Viewing Constraints in the Canvas**
>
> The editor displays all the constraints affecting the currently
> selected view as colored lines on the canvas. The shape, stroke type,
> and line color can tell you a lot about the current state of the
> constraint.
>
> - I-bars (lines with T-shaped end-caps). I-bars show the size of a
>   space. This space can be either the distance between two items, or the
>   height or width of an item.
> - **Plain lines (straight lines with no
>   end-caps).** Plain lines show where edges align. For example, Interface
>   Builder uses simple lines when aligning the leading edge of two or
>   more views. These lines can also be used to connect items that have a
>   0-point space between them.
> - **Solid Lines.** Solid lines represent
>   required constraints (priority = 1000).
> - **Dashed Lines.** Dashed lines
>   represent optional constraints (priority < 1000).
> - **Red Lines.** One of
>   the items affected by this constraint has an error. Either the item
>   has an ambiguous layout, or its layout is not satisfiable. For more
>   information, see the issues navigator or the disclosure arrow in
>   Interface Builder’s outline view.
> - **Orange Lines.** Orange lines indicate
>   that the frame of one of the items affected by this constraint is not
>   in the correct position based on the current set of constraints.
>   Interface builder also shows the calculated position for the frame as
>   a dashed outline. You can move the item to its calculated position
>   using the Resolve Auto Layout Issues tool > Update Frames command.
> - **Blue Lines.** The items affected by the constraint have a nonambiguous,
>   satisfiable layout, and the item’s frame is in the correct position as
>   calculated by the Auto Layout engine.
> - **Equal Badges.** Interface Builder
>   shows constraints that give two items an equal width or an equal
>   height as a separate bar for each item. Both bars are tagged with a
>   blue badge containing an equal (=) sign inside.
> - **Greater-than-or-equal
>   and less-than-or-equal badges.** Interface Builder marks all constraints
>   representing greater-than-or-equal-to and less-than-or-equal-to
>   relationships with a small blue badge with a >= or <= symbol inside.